# Input field is not validating while using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

> Input box requires following validations:
>   1) Length input box should take upto 3 integer length values (decimals not allowed)
>   2) Height input box should take 3 integer number and decimals upto 2 places

Its working fine for the first time, but after clicking **+** button same input fields are opening but now: In the new boxes validations are not working even if I use the same classes for input boxes, i.e, newly added input boxes are taking any number of digits and characters.

**Following is my code:**

```js
var app = angular.module('Calc', []);
var inputQuantity = [];
$(function () {
     $(".form-control").each(function (i) {
          inputQuantity[i] = this.defaultValue;
          $(this).data("idx", i); // save this field's index to access later
     });
     $(".form-control").on("keyup", function (e) {
          var $field = $(this),
               val = this.value,
               $thisIndex = parseInt($field.data("idx"), 10); // retrieve the index
//        window.console && console.log($field.is(":invalid"));
          //  $field.is(":invalid") is for Safari, it must be the last to not error in IE8
          if (this.validity && this.validity.badInput || isNaN(val) || $field.is(":invalid")) {
               this.value = inputQuantity[$thisIndex];
               return;
          }
          if (val.length > Number($field.attr("maxlength"))) {
               val = val.slice(0, 5);
               $field.val(val);
          }
          inputQuantity[$thisIndex] = val;
     });
});
app.controller('Calc_Ctrl', function ($scope, $http) {
     $scope.choices = [{id : 'choice1', l2 : 0, b2 : 0}];
     $scope.areas = [{id : 'choice2', total : 0}];

     $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
          var newItemNo = $scope.choices.length + 1;
          $scope.choices.push({
               'id' : 'choice' + newItemNo, l2 : 0, b2 : 0
          });
     };
     $scope.removeChoice = function () {
          var lastItem = $scope.choices.length - 1;
          if (lastItem !== 0) {
               $scope.choices.splice(lastItem);
          }
     };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="newscript.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="Calc" ng-controller="Calc_Ctrl">
               <div  data-ng-repeat="choice in choices" class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 bottom-line no-gap">
                              <h6>Flooring Area {{$index + 1}} 
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-right-gap  btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="addNewChoice()" style="margin-top: -5px;" id="plus_icon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                                   </button>

                              </h6> 
                              <div class="row walls top-gap">

                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="length">Length :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="length"  ng-model="choice.l2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.00"  >
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="height">Height :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="height"   ng-model="choice.b2" min="0" max="999" maxlength="6" step="0.01">
                                   </div>
                                   <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                        <label for="area">Area sq :</label>
                                        <input type="number" class="form-control text-red bold" id="area" value="{{choice.l2 * choice.b2}}" readonly>
                                   </div>
                                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-right btn-red" aria-label="Left Align"  ng-click="removeChoice()" id="minus_icon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus minus-btn" aria-hidden="true" ></span>
                                   </button>
                              </div>

                         </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I think this is probably because your jQuery block works only when dom is loaded, if you add DOM after, they won't get your code executed on them.

Solution : don't do that, angular has directives to perform validation : use ng-pattern of ng-minlength / ng-maxlength.

Comment: And if you need custome validation, write a custome validation directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#custom-validation

Comment: @Darrick Herwehe, i alreadu used ng-minlength / ng-maxlength but it was not working so  only i used jquey